# Firebase auth identities not updated at security firestore rule level

Tags: firebase, firebase-authentication, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-security

Without triggers on linking new providers in firebase auth cloud functions, I'm trying to keep firestore and auth updated through security rules.

Looking at the [doc](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/rules/rules.firestore.Request), there is a field which contains the identities associated to an user account.

> firebase.identities: A map of all the identities that are associated with this user's account. The keys of the map can be any of the following: email, phone, google.com, facebook.com, github.com, twitter.com. The values of the map are lists of unique identifiers for each identity provider associated with the account. For example, request.auth.token.firebase.identities["google.com"][0] contains the first Google user ID associated with the account.

On all my attempts, it seems that unlinking a provider from an user account does not reflect to that field.

For example, I tried with

```
function isProviderLinked(provider) {
    return provider in request.auth.token.firebase.identities && request.auth.token.firebase.identities[provider].size() > 0
    && request.auth.token.firebase.identities[provider][0] != null
}
```

using facebook.com as provider and it's resulting as isProviderLinked true after the unlinking successful process (logging the user results in facebook provider disappeared).

How I can manage this?